# linq to sql -get data from a table related to another

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Im using linq to sql

i have a Documents table

and a FavouriteDocuments table

FavouriteDocuments table has a documentsID fk and a ProjectID fk.

given the ProjectID how do i get all the documents(from the documents table) that are a FavouriteDocument for that particular project.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Document[] GetFavouriteDocumentsForProject(int projectId)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        return
            (from favourite in db.FavouriteDocuments
            where favourite.ProjectID == projectId
            select favourite.Document).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.